# Get string length after append name

Tags: javascript

If i add a value to a string name i want to get the length of the string not the length of the string name.

```
var wordlist3 = "ABC";
var xc = 3;
var num_words = ('wordlist' + xc).length;
```

With the above code i get wordlist3.length as 9 when it should be 3. How do i append a string name so it references the length of the string in wordlist3, without making it a global var?

Im expecting the answer:

```
num_words = 3
```

not

```
num_words = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to put your word list in arrays.

```
var wordlist = [];
wordlist[0] = 'ABC';
wordlist[0].length;//3
```

You can also use the window object to get at it, if it's in the correct scope

```
window['wordlist' + xc].length;//gives 3
```

Comment: Im working within a game framework so the window option is out of the window. Im using a string as the string is a large dictionary and i need to pull out the string data frequently.

Comment: And you can't use the array method to store it?

Comment: Yes actually i could, is this better than eval?

Comment: If you can go with that, it's the better choice I would say. Eval is generally avoided unless you really must use it. Since the array method is possible, this would be considered better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for that:

```
eval('wordlist' + xc).length;
```